# Why would @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() be DBNull?

Tags: sql, vb.net, identity

**(resolved: see bottom)**

I have the following code snippet:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
Handles SqlDataSource1.Inserted
    affected = CInt(DirectCast(e.Command.Parameters("@affected"), IDbDataParameter).Value)
    newID = CInt(DirectCast(e.Command.Parameters("@newID"), IDbDataParameter).Value)
End Sub
```

Where @newID is defined like this in the SQL string:

```
"INSERT INTO x(a,b,c) VALUES (@a,@b,@c); SELECT @affected = @@rowcount, @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

The parameters are defined using ASP.NET as follows:

The strange thing about it is that this works 90% of the time, but every once and a while it throws an InvalidCastException saying that "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid." Any ideas on what could be causing this value to be null? I don't have any triggers set on the table, and the only thing my query is doing is running a plain insert into 1 table.

**Edit**: Based on the suggestions here, I added an `affected` parameter. I set a breakpoint, and affected = 1 but I still got the exception. However, I then figured out that I had SELECT @newID before SELECT @affected. I switched the order, and now @affected = 0. So it appears to be a problem with my insert statement after all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are there any triggers on the target table?

Comment: You need to post the entire query.

Comment: When the error occurrs, has the row been inserted into the table??

Comment: @amdfan - I think there's a problem with the way in which you've set up @@ROWCOUNT in your SQL string; it will return 1 as it is a global variable and will reference the last statement i.e. SELECT @newID = @@IDENTITY. Simple assignments will return 1 ...

Comment: Ah, you've edited your SQL string now!

Comment: SELECT @affected = @@rowcount, @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); as a single statement would be better...

Comment: @Mitch: good thinking, will do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156208/scope-identity-is-not-working-in-asp-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk
>   copy statement is completed,
>   @@IDENTITY contains the last identity
>   value that is generated by the
>   statement. If the statement did not
>   affect any tables with identity
>   columns, @@IDENTITY returns NULL.

Do you have a check to see if the insert has succeeded? It may be possible that the record you are trying to insert fails to insert anything for some reason, therefore the id is null.

Are there any triggers set up on the table? You may be retrieving the id from a trigger procedure using @@IDENTITY

I would suggest either using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or an [output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(SQL.90).aspx) to get the id

Comment: You can check @@rowcount to see if any rows were actually altered.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2005 onwards, there is also the OUTPUT clause - http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/OUTPUT_clause.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as oppose to `@@IDENTITY` in 99.9% of cases. It is very rare you will have a situation that requires something other than `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

> `@@IDENTITY` returns the last IDENTITY
>   value produced on a connection,
>   regardless of the table that produced
>   the value, and regardless of the scope
>   of the statement that produced the
>   value. If you have a trigger on a
>   table that causes an identity to be
>   created in another table, you will get
>   the identity that was created last,
>   even if it was the trigger that
>   created it.
>
> `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a
>   connection and by a statement in the
>   same scope, regardless of the table
>   that produced the value.
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like @@IDENTITY,
>   will return the last identity value
>   created in the current session, but it
>   will also limit it to your current
>   scope as well.

Are you sure there are no auditing triggers on that table (perhaps added by your DBA)?

Answer (score 2):

Various possibilities:

- INSERT does not insert anything (as
  erikkallen said)
- your statement (not shown) inserts
  to various tables, the last one of
  which does not have an identity
  column
- the INSERT fires a trigger which
  inserts to a table without an
  identity column - try
  SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead

Answer (score 1):

You might want to perform a check to see if @@ROWCOUNT > 0.

Also there were known problems in past versions of SQL Server with triggers impacting the survivability of @@IDENTITY. Do you have any triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Another time when this occurred, changing

```
<asp:Parameter Name="newID" Direction="Output" Size="4" />
```

to

```
<asp:Parameter Name="newID" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" Size="4" />
```

fixed the problem for me. It appeared that my host turned on some requirements for more explicit declaration.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `query text...`  part? An INSERT, I guess.
Could it be an `insert ... select` which didn't find any rows?

Answer (score 0):

[You may receive incorrect values when using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and @@IDENTITY](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779).  Specifically when the query ends up being executed as a parallel query:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779