# SCOPE_IDENTITY is not working in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, identity

I am trying to insert a record and get its newly generated id by executing two queries one by one, but don't know why its giving me the following error.

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types
```

My code is as below: (I don't want to use sql stored procedures)

```
SqlParameter sqlParam;
    int lastInsertedVideoId = 0;

    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ObjUtils._ConnString))
    {
        Conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sqlInsertValues = "@Name,@Slug";
            string sqlColumnNames = "[Name],[Slug]";
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO videos(" + sqlColumnNames + ") VALUES(" + sqlInsertValues + ");";
            sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            sqlParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParam.Value = txtName.Text.Trim();

            sqlParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Slug", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParam.Value = txtSlug.Text.Trim();


            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //getting last inserted video id
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [lastInsertedVideoId]";
            using (SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sqlDr.Read();
                lastInsertedVideoId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDr["lastInsertedVideoId"]);
            }
        }
    }

    //tags insertion into tag table
    if (txtTags.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && lastInsertedVideoId > 0)
    {
        string sqlBulkTagInsert = "";
        string[] tags = txtTags.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string tag in tags)
        {
            sqlBulkTagInsert += "INSERT INTO tags(VideoId, Tag) VALUES(" + lastInsertedVideoId + ", " + tag.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()+ "); ";
        }

        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ObjUtils._ConnString))
        {
            Conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = sqlBulkTagInsert;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

And also if possible, please check is the above code coded well or we can optimize it more for improve performance?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget about the parallel execution bug that exists in SQL Server for SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The call to SCOPE_IDENTITY() is not being treated as being in the same "scope" as the INSERT command that you're executing.

Essentially, what you need to do is change the line:

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO videos(" + sqlColumnNames + ") VALUES(" + sqlInsertValues + ");";
```

to:

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO videos(" + sqlColumnNames + ") VALUES(" + sqlInsertValues + "); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [lastInsertedVideoId]";
```

and then call

```
int lastVideoInsertedId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

instead of .ExecuteNonQuery and the code block following the "//getting last inserted video id" comment.

Comment: I don't know why but its giving me `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` error when I am doing it like `int lastVideoInsertedId = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Got it: I tried it like `int lastVideoInsertedId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());` and its working. I don't know the reason, if you know please explain. And also please edit your answer and include this conversion method. Thanks

Comment: Having just written up a quick test program, it appears that (at least from my contrived example running against Sql Server 2008) the underlying datatype was System.Decimal, rather than the Int32 that I expected, how very bizarre!

Comment: @Prashant Adding Params to the sqlCommand closes the scope after the ExecuteScalar() has run, so the ExecuteNonQuery() is placed into a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` should be extracted from the first command (`SELECT`, `RETURN` or `OUT`) and passed into the next command. By that, I mean that the `SELECT_IDENTITY()` should be at the end of the **first** command. In SQL 2008 there is additional syntax for bring values back as part of the `INSERT`, which makes this simpler.

Or more efficiently: combine the commands into one to avoid round-trips.

Comment: but using `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` how will we get the identity value in a variable? and one more thing I don't want to use sql stored procedures.

Comment: Or it will be nice if you can provide any sample code, thanks.

Comment: If it is an `OUT` param, then `ExecuteNonQuery` is fine - ditto if it is a `RETURN` parameter; if it is a `SELECT`, then use `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar`. Note that an `OUT`/`RETURN` is *marginally* more efficient than `SELECT`, but not by a huge amount.